# Not able to view add item link in list view after 2013 migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, custom-list, migration, list-view-web-part

I have my SharePoint moss site with so many list and their view.
I have add these views on my site pages.

I have migrate this site to SharePoint 2013.
In SharePoint view up-gradation has been done successfully.

But I am not able to view "+ new item" link in my lists, list web part and their views.
From ribbon bar I can add that but I don't want to use it. 
How can I put this link on list template.

I am looking for any solution like using java script, using powershell or manually.

I will be grateful if you can help me out in it.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the list that is lacking the link
- Select the view that doesn’t have the link appearing
- Select Edit Page from the Site Action menu
- Edit the list web part properties
- Note the current Toolbar setting
- Change the Toolbar setting and click Apply. Any selection other than No Toolbar should cause the link to appear after you click Apply.
- Reset the Toolbar setting to that noted  in 5 and click Apply again. The link should be appearing correctly.
- If you need to do this for additional views on the list select the view from the Selected View pull down menu and repeat steps 5 to 7 for each view.
- When complete click the OK button and then click the Stop Editing button in the page ribbon.